# In TCP/IP Socket send, Send data still remains in OS Memory

Tags: c++, c, sockets, send, winsock2

I created a simple chatting client program to communicate with the server.

After the client sent data to the server using the send() function, the data was initialized to memset (buf, 0x00, sizeof(buf)), but after searching OS memory through Dumpit, there are still traces of data sent somewhere.
How can i clear send data?

[image: Screenshot of Dumpit data]

```
int main() {
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET hSocket;
    SOCKADDR_IN servAddr;

    char message[30];
    char tmp[8];
    int strLen;
    memset(tmp, 0x00, 8);

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0)
        ErrorHandling("WSAStartup() error!");

    hSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (hSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        ErrorHandling("socket() error!");

    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("222.106.99.137");
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(atoi("20071"));

    if (connect(hSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        ErrorHandling("connect() error!");

    memcpy(tmp, "thisishell", 7);

    sendto(hSocket, tmp, strlen(tmp) + 1, 0,
        (struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));

    memset(tmp, 0x00, 8);
    memset(tmp, 0xFF, 8);
    memset(tmp, 0x00, 8);

    closesocket(hSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your binary program code still contains the string literal `thisishell`. Most likely, that's what you're seeing, because your other string literals like `"connect() error!"` can be seen right above it in memory.

Comment: Thanks your answer. The example above is a simple case. Even if I don't send it as a string literal on the code and send serial data received from HW to the socket, there is no string on my code, but there is data left.

Comment: That could be in your receive buffer then.